# Android Animation progress listener

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm running a `TranslateAnimation` and I'd need to be able to get the translate values on each 'frame' of the animation. Tried `AnimationListener` but it seems it only listen to `start`, `repeat` and `end` events.

**Is there any way to get interpolated values during an animation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, extend TranslateAnimation and override applyTransformation()